# Getting value in the html table by searching using Jquery and ajax in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I want to Search my data using Id and show it to the html table(Search reasult)
but When I execute the code on the browser and after clicking on the search button It only shows the table(design of the table) without any data.I googled to get hint  but didn't find any appropriate help.

> controller logic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApp.Controllers;
using WebApp.Models;
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class SearchByIdController : Controller
    {
        MvcTstEntities ob = new MvcTstEntities();
        // GET: SearchById
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult Search(string mail)
        {
            var str = (from test in ob.Emp where test.EmailId == mail select test).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

> View Logic

```
<body>


      <form class="form-inline">

          <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <button type="button" id="btnsearch" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div>
          <div class="container" id="tbleshow">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                  <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>

                  </tr>


                      <tr>
                          <td id="ide" ></td>
                          <td id="nm"></td>

                      </tr>

              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tbleshow").hide();

            $("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
                debugger
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#tbleshow").show();
                return myfunction();

            });

            function myfunction() {

                var model = {

                    Email: $("#exampleInputEmail1").val(),



                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/SearchById/Search",
                    dataType: 'json',

                    data: {

                        Email: model.Email,


                    },


                    success: function (run) {

                        $("#ide").val(run.EmailId);
                        $("#nm").val(run.Name);


                        if (run) {

                            alert("This is the details");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Something wrong in success");
                        }

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });
            }





        });
    </script>


</body>
```

Can anyone give me any idea please on how to get the value on table from controller and bind it to the table.

Comment: Is that AJAX callback never reach the controller? I suspected your `data` content passed with wrong parameter.

Comment: so how can I pass the data to the controller?

Comment: Basically this issue is parameter name mismatch and you should match the parameter name for both sides - see the answer for further explanation.

Comment: @geek Does ob.Emp have value in it when you are calling Search? I don't see code where you are setting values to your Ob object, you have just initialized it with a new instance

Comment: of course ob.Emp have value in it

Comment: @geek It could be because of casing issue... check this link https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5046 or https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194... try using run.emailId and run.name

Comment: I solved it instad of using `$("#ide").val(run.EmailId)` and `$("#nm").val(run.Name)` I used `$("#ide").html(run.EmailId)` and `$("#nm").html(run.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using this action method with `mail` as parameter name:

```
public JsonResult Search(string mail)
```

but in your AJAX call's `data` property contains `Email` parameter as shown below, which doesn't match with parameter name defined in controller action method:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "/SearchById/Search",
     dataType: 'json',

     data: {
         Email: model.Email, // this is the wrong part
     },

     success: function (run) {
         // show the results
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
     }
});
```

To conform with AJAX parameter name, you should change action parameter name to `Email`:

```
public JsonResult Search(string Email)
{
    var str = (from test in ob.Emp 
               where test.EmailId == Email 
               select test).FirstOrDefault();
    return Json(str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or else keep the controller action as-is but change the AJAX parameter name to match with controller action parameter name:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "/SearchById/Search",
     dataType: 'json',

     data: {
         mail: $("#exampleInputEmail1").val() // this is correct
     },

     success: function (run) {
         // show the results
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
     }
});
```

**Update:**

If `run` contains JSON string instead of object, you need to parse the string first:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(run);
```

And then use that object to show the values:

```
$("#ide").val(obj.EmailId);
$("#nm").val(obj.Name);
```

Comment: Tried nothing happens

Comment: Try to debug it from client-side, are both `run.EmailId` and `run.Name` returns `undefined`? Is that the controller action now reachable and `mail` contains a value?

Comment: Is the logic of  binding data on html table using ajax is correct?

Comment: The `val()` function should assign all returned data if they're not `undefined`. I didn't see anything wrong with your `success` function, just focused with `data` which causing the problem.

Comment: both [run.EmailId] and [run.Name] returns undefined what should I do

Comment: Check what kind of value contained inside `run`, make sure it contains JSON object instead of JSON string, otherwise you need to parse it by `var obj = JSON.parse(run)` and use `$("#ide").val(obj.EmailId)` afterwards.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: I used <var obj = JSON.parse(run)> but I get the same reasult

Comment: I think there is some data binding problem in html table is there any other way to bind data in the html table

Comment: There is no value passing problem from view page to controller the main problem is table binding to receive the value on table and show it.